# New Tag-Series Request

Tags: support, tags, tag-creation

I've been seeing many Trello questions lately (in my case only 15 days or so....), all wrapped around this one available tag:

> trello

Perhaps we can complement the tag by creating a series, analogue to the following link:

[Trello website](https://trello.com/guide)

**UPDATE:** I've ran thought 50 items of the newest questions, having the trello tag, and  tried to categorize them according to the list below:

1. [trello-boards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-boards)         - 7
2. [trello-cards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-cards)         - 21
3. [trello-card-filter](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-card-filter)
4. [trello-checklist](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-checklist)     - 3
5. [trello-comments](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-comments)      - 4
6. [trello-duedates](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-duedates)
7. [trello-labels](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-labels)
8. [trello-lists](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-lists)         - 6
9. [trello-notifications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-notifications) - 1
10. [trello-organizations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-organizations)- 7
11. [trello-voting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-voting)
12. [trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello)              - 10

Comment: think that's a fair request, but do we have enough questions on each tag to ensure the tag lives?

Comment: The statistics I added, speak for themselves, doesn't? Shall we wait for the consensus (the Dutch way) or shall I make them myself?

Comment: trello-cards and trello-boards are created as new tags. Wiki's are made but you may want to have a look for yourself !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think [trello-cards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-cards), [trello-boards](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-boards) & [trello-organizations](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello-organizations) are good for now - we can expand the others if required.

Comment: Down the line, I've created [tag:trello-lists] as well.....my bad.

Answer (score 1):

These tags would be fine as an addition to the ones already there, but not as a total replacement to the general [trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello) tag that already exists.

Going through and removing that and replacing it with a subset version of the parent is a net loss. It's creating a tagsonomy division that only splits the focus.

The web app is Trello, so it makes sense to have one of the tags on the question be the app it's talking about.

If you want to add another tag, fine.

If you want [to replace](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/posts/36759/revisions) the [trello](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/trello) tag completely, that really doesn't serve an overall good or make any sense.

Comment: It's the same as for the google-drive tag. There the google-spreadsheet tag was/is created as well. Upon questioning, only the trello tag existed.